# fgetcsv() not working with variable $delimiter from $_POST

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I can't get `fgetcsv()` to work with a variable from `$_POST`

```
(  delimiter = (string)$_POST['delimiter'];)
```

I works if I specify: `$delimiter = "\t";`

but not when I use:   `$delimiter = (string)$_POST['delimiter'];`

1. HTML

   ```
   <html>
   <body>
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
           1) Select a delimiter.<br />
           <input type="radio" name="delimiter" value="\t"checked="yes" /> Tab<br />
           <input type="radio" name="delimiter" value=" "/> Space<br />
           <input type="radio" name="delimiter" value=","/> Comma<br />
           <input type="radio" name="delimiter" value=";"/> Semicolon<br /><br />
           <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000">
           2) Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file"><br /><br />
           3) <input type="submit" value="Send Info">
   </form>
   <br />
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: Can you give us a bit more code to review?

Comment: Everything in $_POST is a string already (unless you're using the array notation in your client-side form). What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: Already `$_POST` is a string. Why do you need `(string)` in front of the `$_POST`?

Comment: So is the value of $_POST['delimiter'] a "\t" (in which case it will be treated as '\t' by your code;  or is it %09

Comment: VARDUMP: array(2) { ["delimiter"]=> string(2) "\t" ["MAX_FILE_SIZE"]=> string(4) "1000" }

Comment: I'm having trouble adding my code

Comment: @user2072585 Won't you even see how it shows?

Comment: It looks like PHP is having trouble converting the '\t' string to an actual tab character (usually the difference between single and double quotes). John's answer below should fix it (I accidentally upvoted Praveen's answer as well after slightly misreading the question)

Comment: I changed the value= to "1", "2", "3", and "4" respectively on the HTML page, and used and if/elseif loop on the PHP page to assign a string value to $delimeter.  Ex:  if (1== (int)$_POST['delimiter']) { $delimiter = "\t";"   ...  this seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

Already `$_POST` is a string. Why do you need `(string)` in front of the `$_POST`? Just remove it. Just have:

```
delimiter = $_POST['delimiter'];
```

This should work.

---

Also, you should not use `fgetcsv`, as you aren't fetching a file. You need [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

```
str_getcsv($_POST["csv"], $_POST['delimiter']);
```

Comment: This should not make any difference - it's just a cast - I think url-encoding is more likely to be the problem

Comment: Hmm... May be. Lets see what is the solution.

Comment: Still having problems uploading my code.  I have an HTML form that uploads a selected file and four radio buttons that allow the user to select a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make it foolproof like this:

```
 $options = array(0=> "\t", 1 => "\n");
 $delimiter = $options[ (int) $_POST['delimiter'] ];
```

And use the keys of your options instead of the delimiter itself.
Safer and foolproof.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue and resolve it by following code:

```
$delimiter = $_POST['delimiter'];
$delimiter = str_replace("\\t","\t",$delimiter);
```

Pretty late, but hope it help someone being crazy about this mystery.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use [`stripcslashes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php)

> Returns a string with backslashes stripped off. Recognizes C-like \n, \r ..., octal and hexadecimal representation.

```php
str_getcsv($_POST["csv"], stripcslashes($_POST['delimiter']));
```